# Specifying Sd card mountable as removable disk in android manifest

Tags: android

My android app requires that the device has an SDcard and that SDcard is mountable on a PC or MAC as a FileSystem  (removable disk) . It is because there is a program for windows which my mobile app writes to sd card which user has to run from his PC and that program works on files on that Mounted SD card and disks on PC from windows.

This was a problem on most the Tablets because not all of them can mount their SDcard as removable disk on PC without requiring special drivers on PC for that tablet. But for majority of ICS phones the PC seems to mount the disk as removable storage so I would like to limit my app for the API 8 - API15 (Phones only)

Is there a way to specify in the manifest of an android app that the app should work with an ICS android phone and not the ICS tablets so that users having tablets can not download it from android market ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try specifying screen sizes in the Manifest file http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html. The reason it's hard to differentiate is because tablets and phones essentially run the same software. You might want to look into exactly why the devices don't mount as removable disks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude some devices, there's a "Supported devices" tab on your application page in Developer center, where you may tick checkboxes in front of the models you don't want to support with your software. Besides that, there's not much you can do, because nowadays phones and tablets are pretty much alike, I'm still not sure if Samsung Galaxy Note is a phone or a tablet =)